# In a cmake project, how does one access functions is a different subdirectory?

Tags: c++, subdirectory, cmakelists-options

My directory structure is

```
root
  |- apps
  |    |- source for the target
  |- build
  |    |- where I run cmake ..
  |- containers
  |    |- source for different containers
  |- method1
  |    |- source for method depending on one or more containers
  |- method2
       |- source for method depending on one or more containers
```

My question is:
How do I make my methods see the containers?

I know similar questions have been answered, but I am very new to cmake, and need an explicit answer.

The CMakeLists.txt in the containers directory is:

```
file(GLOB SRC_FILES *.cpp *.h)
add_library(containers ${SRC_FILES})

target_include_directories(containers PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

The other CMakeLists.txt are similar.

A secondary question: Is my directory structure reasonable?

Symptom of problem: During the make phase, I got the following error:

error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Square’ A->print(debug, "\nOriginal A");

Square is one of the containers mentioned in directory structure.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a CMake problem, it sounds like there's something wrong with your code.  Please try to put together a [mre] and add it to your question.

Comment: It is not clear what the reason for your compilation's error message, but one thing is 100% crystal clear: it has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with your project's directory structure or what's in your makefile. Problems related to that will result in completely different error messages.